# creating a mosaic with jai

Tags: java, jai

I am trying to create a concatenation of multiple images into one, but have been having problems. To isolate this I have created the following POC which I am trying to solution in order that I understand how to use the JAI API.

In the POC, I have two images "image1.gif" and "image2.gif" which are both 256x256. The objective is to concatenate them horizontally into a single image "image3.png" which is 512x256. Here is the code I wrote for this using JAI.

```
try {
    InputStream stream1 = new FileInputStream("D:\\poc\\image1.gif");
    InputStream stream2 = new FileInputStream("D:\\poc\\image2.gif");
    RenderedImage image1 = ImageIO.read(stream1);
    RenderedImage image2 = ImageIO.read(stream2);
    ImageLayout imageLayout = new ImageLayout(0,0,512,256);
    RenderingHints renderingHints = new RenderingHints(JAI.KEY_IMAGE_LAYOUT, imageLayout);
    RenderedImage finalImage = MosaicDescriptor.create(new RenderedImage[]{image1, image2}, MosaicDescriptor.MOSAIC_TYPE_OVERLAY, null, null, null, null, renderingHints);
    FileStoreDescriptor.create(finalImage, "D:\\poc\\image3.png", "PNG", null, null, null);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
```

What I get is an image of correct dimensions 512x256, with the first image (image1) in its entirety on the left side of the image, and the right hand side of the image completely black. In other words, it is like I have concatenated the image1.gif with a 256x256 black square.

I have tried changing the MosaicType to MosaicDescriptor.MOSAIC_TYPE_BLEND, but this just creates a similar image only the left half consists of image1 overlaid on top of image2 (or vice-versa) with the right half still completely black.

I have also tried changing the first two parameters of the ImageLayout constructor. This doesn't work either though - for example, I can set the first parameter of ImageLayout to -256, but then image1 is shown on the right half of the image, with the left half of the image black.

Please help!

Comment: I have no idea on how to create a mosaic with JAI but could you please tell me where to download JAI and JAI/ImageIO please? I'm loosing my mind... Thanks!

Comment: hmm that's strange, it seems the link I went to, now no longer exists. However the binaries are still available online at http://download.java.net/media/jai/builds/release/1_1_3/

Comment: yes, very strange.. Thanks a lot though, do you know where to find the   jai-imageio one as well? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what that is - the ImageIO classes were just in my JDK (Java SE 1.6) under rt.jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final  solution I came up with - these generic methods create mosaics of two images to illustrate. You just have to map them to a common co-ordinate space - first create a mosaic of one image (to increase the overall size, as ScaleDescriptor does not work for some reason) and then translate the second one so it can be overlaid with the first.

```
private static RenderedImage horizontalMosaic(RenderedImage image1, RenderedImage image2) {
    ImageLayout imageLayout = new ImageLayout(0, 0, image1.getWidth() + image2.getWidth(), image1.getHeight());
    RenderingHints renderingHints = new RenderingHints(JAI.KEY_IMAGE_LAYOUT, imageLayout);
    RenderedImage image3 = MosaicDescriptor.create(new RenderedImage[]{image1}, MosaicDescriptor.MOSAIC_TYPE_OVERLAY, null, null, null, null, renderingHints);
    RenderedImage image4 = MosaicDescriptor.create(new RenderedImage[]{image2}, MosaicDescriptor.MOSAIC_TYPE_OVERLAY, null, null, null, null, renderingHints);
    RenderedImage image5 = TranslateDescriptor.create(image4, (float)image1.getWidth(), 0.0f, null, renderingHints);
    return MosaicDescriptor.create(new RenderedImage[]{image3, image5}, MosaicDescriptor.MOSAIC_TYPE_OVERLAY, null, null, null, null, renderingHints);
}

private static RenderedImage verticalMosaic(RenderedImage image1, RenderedImage image2) {
    ImageLayout imageLayout = new ImageLayout(0, 0, image1.getWidth(), image1.getHeight() + image2.getHeight());
    RenderingHints renderingHints = new RenderingHints(JAI.KEY_IMAGE_LAYOUT, imageLayout);
    RenderedImage image3 = MosaicDescriptor.create(new RenderedImage[]{image1}, MosaicDescriptor.MOSAIC_TYPE_OVERLAY, null, null, null, null, renderingHints);
    RenderedImage image4 = MosaicDescriptor.create(new RenderedImage[]{image2}, MosaicDescriptor.MOSAIC_TYPE_OVERLAY, null, null, null, null, renderingHints);
    RenderedImage image5 = TranslateDescriptor.create(image4, 0.0f, (float)image1.getHeight(), null, renderingHints);
    return MosaicDescriptor.create(new RenderedImage[]{image3, image5}, MosaicDescriptor.MOSAIC_TYPE_OVERLAY, null, null, null, null, renderingHints);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more concise way to mosaic two images using JAI.  The basic process is to translate (or warp) the source images into the common image space of the mosaic.  Then you can supply all the translated images to the mosaic operation.  There's no need to perform two mosaic operations.  Since the union of the image spaces of all the input images corresponds with the desired output image space of the mosaic, you do not need to supply an ImageLayout as a RenderingHint.  In this example the input images are created in memory, but they could be read in from a file as is done in the original post.

```
   public void makeMosaic(String fileName) throws IOException{
        // Make a black image in memory
        RenderedImage blackImage = ConstantDescriptor.create(256f,256f,new Byte[]{0x00,0x00,0x00},null);
        // Make a white image in memory
        RenderedImage whiteImage = ConstantDescriptor.create(256f, 256f, new Byte[]{(byte) 0xff, (byte) 0xff, (byte) 0xff},null);
        // Translate the white image to shift it 256 pixels to the right
        RenderedImage translatedWhiteImage = TranslateDescriptor.create(whiteImage, 256f, 0f, new InterpolationNearest(), null);
        // Now you can mosaic the two images.  No need to supply an ImageLayout hint or pre-mosaic the black image.
        RenderedImage mosaic = MosaicDescriptor.create(new RenderedImage[]{blackImage,translatedWhiteImage}, MosaicDescriptor.MOSAIC_TYPE_OVERLAY, null, null, null, null, null);
        // Write out the output image.  Should be 256 pixels tall and 512 pixels wide with black tile on left and white tile on right.
        ImageIO.write(mosaic, "PNG", new File(fileName));
    }
```